# EntityManager merge() in JPA

Tags: rest, jpa, merge, entitymanager, dto

I'm working on an application that manages two tables in a database with JPA. The first one contains Users and the second one Items; one user can have many items but an item only corresponds to one user. This means that theres is a One to Many relation from Users to Items and a Many to One relation from Items to Users.

My application is a RESTful service and I am currently transferring DTO's over the web to a web application where the entities information are displayed. When I convert information from a User entity to a User DTO, I cant send all its items, since they can be too many, so I take an entity from the Users database and convert it into a DTO with no Items.

My question is, if I want to update a User's information, when I convert the DTO back to an entity it will not  have any Items, so, how can I save the changes conserving the foreign keys that represent the User items before updating its information?

I know that the EntityManager uses a merge() method to update information in the database, but, wouldn't this affect the foreign keys I want to preserve? since I'm trying to save an Entity with no Items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need simply retrieve a user object from EM,
update the fields that has changed (or all)
commit transaction (if you manage the transaction mannualy)

```
DTO modification = ...
em.getTransaction().begin(); //if it is not container managed
User user = em.find(User.class,modification.getId());
user.setName(modification.getName());
user.setXXX...
em.getTransaction().commit()l //if it is not managed
```

Typically, the items will be lazy loading, so they will not be retrieved at all. Even if, the User object retrived from the JPA will have the full info about them, as long as you are not modifying its itmes content, the items will remain intact.